# Python cs50, o que ocorreu com esse simples código

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Bom dia,

Estou iniciando um curso de Python pela Cs50, porém não entendi o que houve com o código que escrevi.

```py
name = input("Name: ")

print("Hello, " + name)
```

Pode ver que é simples e ainda assim, este erro é mostrado no terminal:

```bsh
Name: alberty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("Name: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'alberty' is not defined
```

O que devo fazer, é alguma configuração ou existe algum erro?

PS: também fiz de outra forma:

```py
print(f"Hello, {name}")
```

E o resultado foi esse:

```bsh
File "name.py", line 2
    print(f"Hello, {name}")
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Você está rodando o código com `Python 2` e este código é `Python 3`. Para usar o Python 2, modifique de `input` para `raw_input` na primeira parte. Nota: f-strings só podem ser usadas em Python 3

Comment: @PauloMarques Só pra ser mais exato, f-strings é a partir do Python 3.6 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro,

O problema é a versão do Python que você está utilizando. Alguns comandos mudaram do Python 2 para o Python 3

### Python 2

```
name = raw_input("Name: ")

print("Hello, " + name)
```

**Nota** O comando `print` pode ou não ter parentesis no Python 2

Outras formas

```
print "Hello, " + name
print "Hello, %s" % name
```

### Python 3

```
name = input("Name: ")

print("Hello, " + name)
```

ou

```
name = input("Name: ")

print(f"Hello, {name}")
```

**Nota** f-strings a partir da versão 3.6.

Sendo assim, use o comando abaixo para rodar seu código:

> python3 name.py

Caso vc não tenha o Python 3 instalado, duas opções:

1. Instale o Python 3
2. Modifique o código para Python 2

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Agradeço, não sabia que existiam versões para rodar o mesmo programa, ainda mais que se pode usar mods antigos para fazer a mesma coisa. Muito obrigado.